# What should I know before changing my development database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite

Since I learned Rails from Micheal Hartl's tutorial, all of my apps are set up to use SQLite3 in development, but Postgresql in production.   This is causing problems with searches that work in development but not in production.  From other Stack overflow questions, I've learned that using different databases in different environments is a bad idea.

I think that my best solution is to change the development database to Postgresql.  But I'm sure that it's not as simple as adjusting the db name in my gemfile.  What other changes will I need to make?  What are some potential side effects that I should be aware of?

Thank you in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it two ways.

**First Way :**

Below are steps you can follow to convert sqlite to postgres.

- Install postgres.
- Change your Gemfile in your rails app and add PG gem.
- Run bundle install.
- Change the database.yml file to use postgres.
- Run `rake db:setup` followed by `rake db:migrate`.

Everything should work as expected, Because with `rake db:setup` and `rake db:migrate` you will get identical database as before.

**Second Way :**

Now rails also provide way to directly change DB from one DB to another, You can check [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/34832).

Just use below command and you are done.

```
bin/rails db:system:change --to=postgresql
```

**Copy Data as well :**

If you want to copy data as well you can use [yaml_db](https://github.com/yamldb/yaml_db) gem.